# How to change background color of Android Material ChipGroup?

Tags: android, material-design, background-color, android-chips

I need to dynamically change the background color of the Android Material chips container (`ChipGroup`) component. I tried `setBackground()` and `setBackgroundTint()`. I also tried `android:background` and `android:backgroundTint` properties in XML (code below) just to check. But they are not working either. Any idea how to do this?

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chips"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@color/tw__transparent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/tw__transparent"
    app:ensureMinTouchTargetSize="false"
    app:chipSpacing="2dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in java file.

```
// Defined in colors.xml - #ca8eed
chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.chip)
```

And if you want to change textColor, you can use style

in styles.xml file,

```
<resources>
   ...
    <style name="ChipTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#2b90ff</item>
    </style>
  ...
```

and add style in layout xml file.

Comment: I think Kulakshi asked to change ChipGroup background color not the chip background color

Comment: oh. sorry. then just cover other layout and set background color in covered layout is easy way. I think

Answer (score 0):

The `ChipGroup` is just a `ViewGroup`. You can use :

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:background="@color/...."
```

or you can use the **`setBackgroundColor`** method:

```
chipGroup.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color...));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a layout (Linear or Relative) including the chips and set the background color to that layout, easy way.